# Multiple xsd schemas in ws message validator - why is the resource not found in schemaCollection but found in xsdSchema?

Tags: java, xsd, spring-ws

I'm trying to find out why using a SimpleXsdSchema to set an XSD resource works

```
<bean id="xsdSchema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
    <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/schema.xsd"/>
</bean>
```

whereas using CommonsXsdSchemaCollection does not. I intend to use it to provide multiple xsd's. I prefer this approach to importing xsd inside one another.

```
<bean id="schemaCollection"
      class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">
    <!--<property name="resourceLoader" ref="resourceLoader"/>-->
    <property name="xsds">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/schema.xsd"</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="inline" value="true" />
</bean>
```

When using it as marked below the error is: `ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/schema.xsd"] does not exit`

Precisely

```
 Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]: 
 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'schemaCollection' while setting bean property 'schemaCollection'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating  bean with name 'schemaCollection' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/schema.xsd"] does not exit
```

Usage:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="errorHandler" ref="customValidationErrorHandler"/>
        <!--<property name="xsdSchema" ref="xsdSchema"/>-->
        <property name="schemaCollection" ref="schemaCollection"/>
    </bean>
```

Does anyone have a clue about it?
Is there a resourceLoader that i should use? (The app get packed in war and deployed to an application server where it remains unexploded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your config:

```
        <value>/WEB-INF/schema.xsd"</value>
```

This should be:

```
        <value>/WEB-INF/schema.xsd</value>
```

Comment: Indeed, it seems I was really tired when i wrote that. Thanks!